# How to digitally control a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, voltage-source, powermosfet, buck-boost

I'm trying to make a temperature controller for peltier module using MOSFET. The peltier uses 3.3 to 12 volts and 15A. So far I've only come across a way in which the circuit uses a potentiometer at the gate & drain to control the MOSFET source output. I'm looking for a way in which the microcontroller can automatically control the voltage from a feedback loop. I've come across some digital potentiometers but they can't handle 15A. Any help?

By the way, I'm not an electronics engineer. Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear from your question what you're trying to achieve. *a way in which the microcontroller can automatically control the voltage from a feedback loop* That makes no sense to me, draw a block diagram to show what functionality you want. Stop thinking in implementation like "digital potmeter" as that's **unusable** for these kinds of things. I suggest you get a ready made temperature controller with a relay and use that. Using the MOSFET as a variable resistor with 15 A flowing is a sure way to **kill the MOSFET**. No need to be an EE as long as you can design/understand circuits.

Comment: Do you know how to program AVR microcontroller ?? Say ATMEGA 8 / ATTINY13 .

Comment: I can give you an answer based on AVR microcontroller.

Comment: @SadatRafi Yes I can program an AVR using Arduino.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm trying to upload I've but the phone app is having trouble. I'll do it again..

Comment: ok .. I'm giving you an algorithm that I've been using for 6 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to mechanically kill a Peltier is to switch it on and off sufficiently infrequently that it changes temperature, anything longer than a few seconds for instance. Thermal cycling degrades them.

A Peltier shifts heat proportional to the average current, but generates waste heat proportional to the current squared, so even fast PWM gives you a much lower efficiency than steady DC of the correct value. Use a proper buck converter with an output filter for controlling the current rather than simple PWM.

If you compare a linear FET control with buck converter, the overall efficiency will be very low for the linear regulator. In addition, a FET does not make a good linear regulator. Most BJTs, but few FETs, are rated for steady power dissipation. A good way to destroy a typical power FET is to let it dissipate steady power, even when well heatsunk, and well within its headline maximum power.

So, get a design for a buck converter, and build one of those round your controller. Or buy one.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice. I did some research on the internet and I came across this implementation: https://www.electronics-lab.com/how-to-control-lm2596-buck-converter-with-microcontroller/. Can  be done tour 300W buck converter?

Comment: *can the same be done to a 300W buck converter?

Comment: @user250889 Different buck converter ICs may have different voltage control arrangements, so you may not be able to use the identical setup. In principle, there's no reason why any adjustable converter can't be controlled in a similar way. As the application is to power a peltier, there's no requirement for a super-clean output, just an output which is not PWM'd full on and full off. Find a likely buck converter, link to it, and I'll have a look and advise you.

Comment: https://shop2india.com/300w-20a-dc-buck-module-constant-current-adjustable-step-down-converter-vol/

Comment: @akshaykumark There's no indication of what IC it uses from that listing. However, as they say 'minimum output voltage 1.2 V', it's likely it uses the same control strategy as the other one. As there's an accessible CV control, it's likely it will be easy enough to find and connect to. However, 'likely' is not the same as 'guaranteed', so it would be at your own risk. If you can find out what IC it uses, that would be better.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

First, establish a linear relationship between the temperature and PWM. I have plotted temperature in the x-axis and OCR register value (OCR controls the PWM) in the y-axis.

For example, I want that when the temperature is 0-degree Celsius, the pulse width will be 100% (i.e. OCR value 255). And when the temperature is 70-degree Celsius, the pulse width will be 0% (i.e. OCR value 0).

So, the relationship between the temperature and pulse width will be: **y=255-3.642857x**
Here, x is the current temperature and y is the OCR value corresponding to it.

If your sensor is analog then you have to use ADC. Then the x-coordinate value will be the ADC value.

Use the pulses to drive a MOSFET or IGBT.

Comment: I'll try this also.. Thanks.

Comment: @akshaykumark, use a capacitor to filter the output of the MOSFET. It will act as buck converter. You can't interface an external buck converter module with the microcontroller. That's more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Neil_UK,

but to answer your question, you could use PWM-modulation where you filter the output with an RC-link in such a away that the ripple will be negligible.

One other way could be to use an ADC to an OP-amp to buffer the signal to the gate.